# Vimeo API PHP call

Tags: php, vimeo-api

Im trying to get make a basic api call. I did everything which is mentioned here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start

```
require '{path_to_root_folder}/autoload.php';
use Vimeo\Vimeo;

$client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

$response = $client->request('/tutorial', array(), 'GET');
print_r($response);
```

But i get an Error 500:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Vimeo\\Vimeo' not found in ../test/vimeo.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in ../test/vimeo.php on line 4
```

My server runs php 7.2

What is the issue here? Help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you are including autoload.php like this :
    require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

It says that your class is not found, you can run 
   composer dump-autoload 
to rebuild your class path loader array.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, after trying to install it directly on my hosting, Im getting new Errors: Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in ../test/vimeo.php on line 3 - Warning: require_once(../test/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in ../test/vimeo.php on line 3 - Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'www.domain.com/test/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php/7.2.26/share/pear') in .../test/vimeo.php on line 3

Comment: It used to be so easy getting videos from vimeo. Now Im almost fed up after hours and hours of trying :(

Comment: well. I got it. Yeehaa. Was the wrong path! Thanks anyway.